# Using validation and training dataset in a RandomForest

Tags: r, validation, classification, random-forest, training-data

I'm here to ask a basic question about the use of the `RandomForest` function in the `RandomForest package`.
I am using the `RF algorithm` to perform a land cover classification.

I have got some `geo-spatial` data which I divided into a training dataset (pks_trainingdf) and a validation dataset (pks_validationdf).

Each `df` contains 34 columns; the first 33 columns are the bands that I want to use for the classification; the last column ("class") contains the classes, which are supposed to be the output of the `RF` classification.

My question is: which dataset is the argument of `x` and which of `xtest`?
Is the following line of code correct?

```
modelRF_5 <- randomForest(x=pks_validationdf[, c(1:33)],
                       y=pks_validationdf$class, xtest=pks_trainingdf[, c(1:33)],
                       ytest=pks_trainingdf$class, importance=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is for the training subset while xtest is for test or validation subset. In your case it looks you inverse.  it is only not important if both have same size (that is not the case usually).  It is important  you  randomized the data set before splitting into training and validation subsets. If not you should change it. In addition, it is safer to split in three subset rather than 2. One for training, other for validating the model and the last for reporting the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for! So, I obtained my training and validation dataset with a Random Samping, so it should be fine, right? And if I want to divide the dataset into three parts, how would it work? x would be training dataset, xtest the test dataset for reporting error, so where would the validation dataset go...?

Comment: what if I have training pixels + validation pixels + unknown pixels (the last ones to be classified)?

Comment: If you have the 3 subsets use first the validation one to tune the model and to decide the training size. You can do that plotting learning curves and using the elbow method. The other partition (test) is the one you are going to use to check and report the final accuracy and  error measure of your model.

Comment: First use validation set, tune and diagnosis the model and then use test set for final error report. Pleasure to help.